# Running UWP unit tests in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, visual-studio-2017

For some reason Visual Studio 2017 does not recognize unit tests in Universal Windows Unit Test App projects.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new **Unit Test App (Universal Windows)** in VS 2017
2. Add `Assert.IsTrue(true);` to the unit test created
3. Click on **Test -> Run -> All Tests**

Expected: unit test discovered and run successfully.

Actual: no tests found.

Output *Tests* produces absolutely no output.

Comment if there is a log file containing some more info and I'll add it.

EDIT: So it turns out **they don't work in 2015 either**. I have ReSharper in 2015 which *is* able to run them. But why can't the VS runner run them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This now works in Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.4.5 currently).

After building the solution, the tests appear right away. Deploying the test project may have also worked in the older versions.

Comment: I still have to deploy the test app before any tests will show. I also have to deploy the app after any changes to code at all or it will not use the latest changes. It seems since UWP is "sandboxed" you need to deploy so it will run the tests from the appx location and not the bin folder. Really a productivity killer since every modification, you need to deploy. I'm currently using VS Professional 2017 15.5.2.

Answer (score 2):

By sheer dumb luck (or just desperation), I went to my Test project and Deployed it (right click on project-> Deploy). That made the tests appear and now they run.

Comment: Actually it is possible this was the problem back then. How does this not answer the question? My question was how do I get the unit tests to run in VS 2017, and Fernando answered "By deploying the test app".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It seems since UWP is "sandboxed" you need to deploy so it will run the tests from the appx location and not the bin folder. Any modifications to tests (and the classes they are testing), you need to deploy prior to running tests.